# How can I disable Windows 8's touch instructions?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, touchscreen

Windows 8.1 features new on-screen instructions on how to use the touch gestures that aren't necessarily obvious. The instructions require actually performing the gestures to disappear. Until then, those instructions cover a large part of the app I'm currently seeing.

The thing is, that system is running in a VMware console and I simply can't perform a gesture from outside the screen. That would be outside the VMware window. And the moment I switch to fullscreen mode the instruction disappears. I think I managed to pass level 1 somehow, but I'm currently stuck in level 2 (the swipe from the left side).

Now how can I teach Windows 8.1 that I'm not interested in learning touch gestures on a virtualised keyboard-and-mouse system? There must be some setting or registry key, or file to delete or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Eightforums posted a guide](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/31098-help-tips-enable-disable-windows-8-1-a.html) how to do this.

Run the Group Policy Editor, go to `User Configuration->Administrative Templates->Windows Components->Edge UI` and set the option `Disable help tips` to `enabled`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Need to re-login to apply the setting. (Press Windows+R and run "logoff" to log out, can't find a UI for that.)